# HTML help - find a way to add a hidden value into a td field

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML table where I'm building an edit function to change a field inside this table.
I'd like your help to find a way to store the ID of the data listed in this field.
As a matter of fact, I have an object that has the listed data, `RoleName`, inside a `<td>`, and I'd like to store its id too, doing something like:

```
 foreach ($accountUsers as $accountUser){
      <td value="$accountUser->roleID">$accountUser->getRoleName()</td>
```

The problem is that `value` is not a property of a `td`. My constraint is that I must continue with the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, you can use HTML5 [`data-*`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#attr-data-%2a) attributes to store arbitrary data on an element:

```
<td data-value="$accountUser->roleID">$accountUser->getRoleName()</td>
```

**Update** (see comments)

You can access this data via the jQuery [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method:

```
var value = $(yourTd).data("value");
```

Alternatively, you can use the native [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute) method:

```
var value = yourTd.getAttribute("data-value");
```